# Chart JS not displaying bars/labels on graph

Tags: php, laravel, graph, charts, chart.js

I am using Laravel 10, and Chart.JS for graphs on my site.

I've got the stats loaded from the database, however, when creating the graph it shows me (https://i.stack.imgur.com/QT0s7.jpg) the graph lines, and the numbers up the side correctly but no bars or labels.

To get the information:

```
$stats = UserCountStats::query()
            ->start(now()->subMonths(2))
            ->end(now()->subSecond())
            ->groupByWeek()
            ->get();
```

**My code to generate the graph:**

```
<script>
        // Retrieve the statistical data from laravel-stats
        var statsData = {!! json_encode($stats) !!};

        // Process the data and create the chart
        var labels = statsData.map(stat => stat.period);
        var values = statsData.map(stat => stat.value);

        // Create the Chart.js bar chart
        var ctx = document.getElementById('userCountChart').getContext('2d');
        var userCountChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: labels,
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'User Count',
                    data: values,
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                    borderColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                    borderWidth: 1
                }]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    x: {
                        grid: {
                            display: true
                        }
                    },
                    y: {
                        beginAtZero: true // Ensure the y-axis starts at 0
                    }
                },
                plugins: {
                    legend: {
                        display: false // Hide the legend
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        callbacks: {
                            label: function(context) {
                                return 'User Count: ' + context.parsed.y;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
```

**Stats passed**
[{"start":"2023-06-05T00:00:00.000000Z","end":"2023-06-12T00:00:00.000000Z","value":0,"increments":0,"decrements":0,"difference":0},{"start":"2023-06-12T00:00:00.000000Z","end":"2023-06-19T00:00:00.000000Z","value":0,"increments":0,"decrements":0,"difference":0},{"start":"2023-06-19T00:00:00.000000Z","end":"2023-06-26T00:00:00.000000Z","value":0,"increments":0,"decrements":0,"difference":0},{"start":"2023-06-26T00:00:00.000000Z","end":"2023-07-03T00:00:00.000000Z","value":0,"increments":0,"decrements":0,"difference":0},{"start":"2023-07-03T00:00:00.000000Z","end":"2023-07-10T00:00:00.000000Z","value":0,"increments":0,"decrements":0,"difference":0},{"start":"2023-07-10T00:00:00.000000Z","end":"2023-07-17T00:00:00.000000Z","value":0,"increments":0,"decrements":0,"difference":0},{"start":"2023-07-17T00:00:00.000000Z","end":"2023-07-24T00:00:00.000000Z","value":0,"increments":0,"decrements":0,"difference":0},{"start":"2023-07-24T00:00:00.000000Z","end":"2023-07-31T00:00:00.000000Z","value":4,"increments":4,"decrements":0,"difference":4},{"start":"2023-07-31T00:00:00.000000Z","end":"2023-08-07T00:00:00.000000Z","value":7,"increments":3,"decrements":0,"difference":3},{"start":"2023-08-07T00:00:00.000000Z","end":"2023-08-14T00:00:00.000000Z","value":11,"increments":4,"decrements":0,"difference":4}]

I've tried for a while, and can't figure this out.

Comment: Can you show us the actual JSON you are passing to `statsData`?

Comment: There isn't a property named `period` anywhere in there, and therefor `var labels = statsData.map(stat => stat.period);` got you an array containing ten times `undefined`.

Comment: @CBroe hahaha shot mate, I used AI to make this for me (I ceebs learning ChartJS right now) - but I got a working version from what you've stated so I appreciate that :)